# Go to next level when Key is grabbed by Player Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help with a feature I'm implementing for a game made in Unity 2D.
The player must take a key in order to unlock a door (maybe showing an animation) and when the player go in front of that door if he has the key, he will automatically go to the next level.
I need help, cause the door is not letting go to the next level.

Here is the KEY code/script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class KeyScript : MonoBehaviour {

    //public AudioSource coinSoundEffect;
    public AudioClip key1;

    void Awake () {

        //source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other) {
        Debug.Log("Chiave Presa");

        if(other.gameObject.tag =="Player")
            GameObject.Find("KeyDoor").SendMessage("HitKey");
        SoundManager2D.playOneShotSound(key1);
    }

}
```

Here is the DOOR code/script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DoorScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool key = false;
    public string nextLevelName;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void HitKey (){
        Debug.Log("La porta è sbloccata");
        key = true;
        Destroy (GameObject.Find ("Key"));
    }


    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other){
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            if (key == true){
                Application.LoadLevel(nextLevelName);
                //Destroy(gameObject);
                //GameObject.Find("Key").SendMessage("DestroyKey"); //If you also want to destroy the key
                //GoToNextLevel ();

            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collision2D other)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(nextLevelName);
    }

    public virtual void GoToNextLevel()
    {
        //loadingImage.SetActive(true);
        Application.LoadLevel(nextLevelName);

    }


}
```

The code works but when the player goes in front of the door, he is not passing to the next level.
Any help or hint appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `GameObject.Find("KeyDoor").GetComponent<DoorScript>().SendMessage("HitKey");`? Or simplier `GameObject.Find("KeyDoor").GetComponent<DoorScript>().key = true;`

Comment: @m.rogalski I put this GameObject.Find("KeyDoor").GetComponent<DoorScript> on the key script, but still not working.

Comment: Are you sure that all of the `GameObject`s have theirs `Collider`s attached and working ?

Comment: @m.rogalski Now worked but I have another problem, into the door script I'd like to load the next level in another way, cause in the way I wrote it is not easy. It means I need to make a script for the door in every level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're missing one thing:

**[unity](/questions/tagged/unity) is `Component` based engine**

This means you should make interactions between `Component`s, not `GameObject`s.

In your script there's a `public` field `public bool key` which should not be accessible from the outside. But if you're looking for simple and **wrong** answer that **will work** then you can just replace this line :

```
GameObject.Find("KeyDoor").SendMessage("HitKey");
```

Into this one :

```
GameObject.Find("KeyDoor").GetComponent<DoorScript>().key = true;
```

In that case you'll end up with messy code and unstable game. What I can recommend to you as an good alternative is to rewrite your logic a bit.

Instead of making a `MonoBehaviour` which is not needed you can just create a `Component` :

```
public class KeyComponent : Component
{
    [SerializeField]
    AudioClip m_KeyPickupSound;

    [SerializeField]
    bool m_IsPickedUp;

    public bool PickedUp
    {
        get { return m_IsPickedUp; }
    }

    public void PickUp()
    {
        m_IsPickedUp = true;
        SoundManager2D.playOneShotSound(m_KeyPickupSound);
    }
}
```

Now attach this into your `Player`'s `Component`s list and in your door script do:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.GetComponent<KeyComponent>() != null && other.GetComponent<KeyComponent>().PickedUp)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    } 
}
```

Now only thing left is to update your `Player`'s `MonoBehaviour` and add simple collision check :

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.tag == "TAG_FOR_KEY")
        GetComponent<DoorScript>().PickUp();
}
```

Now you're interacting with `Component`s and not `GameObject` which then require less effort changing some scripts.

Comment: Wow man, thanks. This is a very useful alternative to MonoBehaviour

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your player needs to have a `Rigidbody2D` and a `Collider2D` and the door has a `Collider2D` component

If your doors `Collider2D` is a trigger you must use void `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)`.

Another problem may be that "Level 2" isn't added to your build settings, make sure that it is added to the level's list.

Answering your last comment as it seemed the problem was that the `Collider2D` on the door, you can make this in a lot of ways, the easiest way is this:

Add a public string variable called `nextLevelName` in your Door's script, then when calling `LoadLevel`, use this variable. You can change the value from the inspector in each level. The problem with this is that if you rearrange the levels then you need to change the strings in each level.

The best solution in that case is this one:

```
int currentLevelNum = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
SceneManager.LoadScene(currentLevelNum+1);
```

This way if you have your levels in order in your build settings you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Yes but the door with Rigidbody2D is falling down, even if there is a box collider 2D as ground for physics.

Comment: The door doesn't need a rigidbody if the player has one.

Comment: @GunnarB. The door falls down when I flag Is Trigger on Box Collider 2D.

Comment: @Juan Bayona Beriso I fixed the problem now everything is working. Can you help me here? Into the door script I'd like to load the next level in another way, cause in the way I wrote it is not easy. It means I need to make a script for the door in every level

Comment: @Juan Bayona Beriso can You check my edited code and see if it is okay? thanks dude for your help

Comment: The code now looks fine, just remember to change the value of nextLevelName in the inspector of every scene.

Comment: @JuanBayonaBeriso Thanks dude! You really helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should change `Application.LoadLevel` to `SceneManager.LoadScene`. The first is obsolete in the newer versions of unity.

Second you need to make sure that your scenes are actually registered in **File -> BuildSettings** and the parameter you pass to `LoadScene` matches either the index in that list or the name as string.

Comment: Into the door script I'd like to load the next level in another way, cause in the way I wrote it is not easy. It means I need to make a script for the door in every level. I'd like to set the scene to load though a private or public string that I will edit in every scene.

Comment: Sure, you can use a public string (or int) to set the next level for a door. You just need to make sure to match the build settings list.